# Perforce: how to see if some changes are inside a branch at a specific revision?

Tags: perforce, perforce-integrate, perforce-stream

This is not an easy question, so I'll try my best to explain it with a simplified example...

We have 2 branches (potentially more): `main` and `dev`. Development is done in `dev`, si it gets multiple CLs. Some time to time, we full integrate `dev` into `main`: we take all the changes done in `dev` and we put them in `main` in a single *full-integrate* CL.

```
  dev   main
   │      │
 W ├─────►│ A full integrate W
   │      │
 X ├─────►│ B full integrate X
   │      │
 Y │      │
   │      │
 Z ├─────►│ C full integrate Y and Z
   │      │
```

Now, I want to know if I have `Y` in `main` at a specific CL. For example:

- do I have `Y` in `main@A`: *NO*
- do I have `Y` in `main@B`: *NO*
- do I have `Y` in `main@C`: *YES*

I want a command line that will give me this result. So far, I am using :

```
p4 integrate -n "//dev/...@Y,@Y" //main/...
```

Because it *tries* to integrate `Y` in `main` and tells if something should be done or not. If not, we already have the changes, nothing to be done.

The problem is that with this command, as soon as `Y` gets integrated into `main`, it will always say that it is here as we can't provide a CL for the target branch `main`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-C` flag to `p4 integrate`.  The `-C` flag limits the integration records considered to those that are <= the given changelist; it's meant for this exact problem.

For example:

```
p4 integ -n -C B //dev/...@Y,Y //main/...  # no
p4 integ -n -C C //dev/...@Y,Y //main/...  # yes
```

See `p4 help undoc`:

```
    p4 integrate -1 -2 -C changelist# -Rlou -Znnn
        ... The -C
        changelist# flag considers only integration history from changelists
        at or below the given number, allowing you to ignore credit from
        subsequent integrations. ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed it in the doc... Though, it seems it works well for the example I shew, but it doesn't seem to work for this check: `p4 integrate -n -C Y //main/...@C,@C //dev/...`, where I want to know if on `dev@Y` I have all CLs from `main@C`

Comment: Bit of a weird edge case there -- given that `Y < C` I'd expect that the command should tell you no since it should be filtering out the Z -> C integration that would grant reverse credit, but you should be able to just assume it without running the command since it's obviously not possible to have credit for something that hasn't happened yet.  :)